# Android: Why marquee on TextView works for English Text, but not for Arabic Text?

Tags: android, textview, right-to-left, marquee

I want to apply Marquee on Arabic Text in a TextView. Following code works fine for English text, but does not work for Arabic text. Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/tVMessage"
            style="@style/tVMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textDirection="anyRtl"
            android:text="Good bye Good bye Good bye Good bye Good bye Good bye Good bye Good bye Good bye Good bye Good bye Good bye Good bye Good bye Good bye Good bye Good bye Good bye Good bye Good bye Good bye Good bye" />


<style name="tVMessage">
        <item name="android:lines">1</item>
        <item name="android:ellipsize">marquee</item>
        <item name="android:fadingEdge">horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:marqueeRepeatLimit">marquee_forever</item>
        <item name="android:scrollHorizontally">true</item>
        <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
        <item name="android:focusableInTouchMode">true</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this programmatically not from xml:

```
textView.setSingleLine(true);
textView.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
textView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
textView.setFreezesText(true);
textView.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
textView.setFocusable(true);
textView.setSelected(true);
```

With xml you use this :

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/tVMessage"
            style="@style/tVMessage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textDirection="anyRtl"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Good bye Good bye Good bye Good bye Good bye Good bye Good bye Good bye Good bye Good bye Good bye Good bye Good bye Good bye Good bye Good bye Good bye Good bye Good bye Good bye Good bye Good bye" />
```

use single line in your xml.

Comment: but SharjeelNisar mention clearly harshit that his Following code works fine for English text, but does not work for Arabic only

Comment: BhanuSharma try this at your end you will find error of that code.